# Ошибка "Невозможно создать массив типа ..., так как базовый тип значения слишком велик"

Tags: c#

Есть задача: измерить время выполнения разных операций с разными коллекциями с разными типами данных.

Код класса коллекции:

```
public class LinkedQueueLarge
{
    LinkedList<LargeData> _LinkedList = new LinkedList<LargeData>();

    public void Add(LargeData data)
    {
        _LinkedList.AddLast(data);
    }

    public LargeData Rem()
    {
        LargeData data = _LinkedList.First();
        _LinkedList.RemoveFirst();
        return data;
    }
}
```

Данные для наполнения:

```
unsafe public struct LargeData
{
    public fixed byte a[102400];
}
```

И код, во время выполнения которого возникает ошибка:

```
float lql1 = 0,
LinkedQueueLarge LQL = new LinkedQueueLarge();
textBox1.Text += "LinkedQueue, Large Data\n";
for (int i = 0; i < 2500; i++)
{
    int StartTime;
    int ResultTime;
    StartTime = Environment.TickCount;
    LQL.Add(new LargeData());
    ResultTime = Environment.TickCount - StartTime;
    lql1 += ResultTime;
}
```

Сама ошибка:

> System.InvalidProgramException: "Компилятор JIT обнаружил внутреннее
>   ограничение."

И ещё в `LQL._linkedList.Message` (что это вообще?) в отладке при остановке из-за ошибки значение:

> Невозможно создать массив типа "LargeData" из сборки "lab07,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null", так как
>   базовый тип значения слишком велик.

Comment: А вы осознанно используете небезопасный буфер фиксированного размера? Если, например, просто сделать `public struct LargeData { public byte[] a; }` и вызывать как `LQL.Add(new LargeData { a = new byte[102400] });`, то подобных проблем не будет.

Comment: В указаниях по выполнению лабы было так написано. До конца смысл изначальной конструкции не улавливаю.
Спасибо, так работает.

Comment: Есть, например, [небольшая статья в документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/fixed-size-buffers) по этому поводу. На какие-то базовые моменты она способна пролить свет.